# heroku rejected git push with warnings " DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins" and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

Heroku is rejecting the push with the following message:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out
and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on
this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73
cc961fb8d2/Rakefile:7)
       DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out
and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on
this:  (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73
cc961fb8d2/Rakefile:7)
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgre
sql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgre
sql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgre
sql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgre
sql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgre
sql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgre
sql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac
t/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `cle
ar_cache!'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2
 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run
__1575907776091260551__prepare__1163126976531258673__callbacks'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__ru
n_callback'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run
_prepare_callbacks'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_c
allbacks'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:i
n `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:i
n `prepare!'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in
 <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_in
itializers'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializer
s'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_m
issing'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `r
equire'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `b
lock in require'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `l
oad_dependency'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `r
equire'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environm
ent!'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels)
 in initialize_tasks'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 level
s) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 level
s) in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_rebo
ot_rake_task'
       /tmp/build_c758e521-24e9-4477-b6d7-73cc961fb8d2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 level
s) in <top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I've tried other's solutions in Stackoverflow without any success:

1. include gem rails_12factor
2. add the line "    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false" in the application.rb
3. putting Sql3lite gem in the development/test group

and I've also tried some of my own including:

1. create a new stack cedar application
2. add a new SSH key
3. installed Heroku toolbelt.
4. commenting out PG gem in production
5. remove Gemfile.lock

My code is at https://github.com/charleshsu168/sample_app1
I am folloing Michael Hartl tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The DEPRECATION WARNING: 's are unrelated to your issue, I get them on my live servers.

It looks like Rails thinks that your DB server is available locally hence it is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost.

Based on the logs, looks like a DB configuration issue. Do you have postgres configured correctly. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby.

postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work somehow by trial and error. One of the thing I did is I deleted the old Heroku remote URL that doesn't exist anymore in .git/config, replace it with the new Heroku app name I've created, and then re-run: Heroku push master
Now it works!